# Map city names to countries - python?

Tags: python, nlp, data-science, data-extraction

I have a dataframe that represents the location of some people.

This dataframe is not cleaned and the names are a mess. some rows have only the country name, others have name and city, and others have only the city. I also have sentences that are not in English.

How can I use python with NLP to tidy this dataset and get a homogenous dataset?

Here is a screenshot of the dataset:
[image]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm unable to comment, but you weren't clear what exactly you want to extract from this series? If you were just trying to find every instance of "Named Location" and make new Series from them, you probably are looking for [Named Entity Recognition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named-entity_recognition) (NER). [NLTK](https://www.nltk.org/) is a good place to start with NER, and they have [a pretty good tutorial](https://www.nltk.org/book/ch07.html) on how to use it for getting specific types of named entities (see Section 5, Named Entity Recognition).

In short I would start with something like

```
import nltk
ser = #<your series of strings>
locations = df.apply(lambda x:nltk.ne_chunk(nltk.pos_tag(nltk.word_tokenize(str(x)))))
```

But NLP is a complicated task, and [as has been discussed](https://towardsdatascience.com/named-entity-recognition-with-nltk-and-spacy-8c4a7d88e7da), NER is particularly difficult.